# Running a java class file using unix syntax?

Tags: java, unix, command-line

I'm writing a script to validate I/O for contest problem solutions under a given directory for any of the following language types:

- binary files (c, c++, etc.)
- java classes
- scripts (ruby, python, etc.)

I noticed the only one of the three above listed types that cannot be executed in a unix-style syntax `./program < sometest.in` is Java.  Obviously it's not difficult to simply check file extension in the script and replace above command with format `java program < sometest.in`, but it made me curious:

Is there a way to use unix-style syntax to run a Java class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to wrap your Java class / JAR file into a little shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

read input
java -jar program.jar $input
```

Make the file executable:

```
chmod a+x program
```

Use it as suggested in your question:

```
./program < sometest.in
```